# Memory Alignment For Global/Local Variables in C

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, compiler-construction

In C if I create a structure like

```
typedef struct A
{
  int a;
  char b;
} sampleType __attribute__ ((aligned (128)));
```

All the variables of this type would be aligned by 128 bit boundary.

Is it same for the global and local variables of this type?
Or does it differ from compiler to compiler?
How does GCC/LLVM handle them?

Comment: Note that __ attribute __ is a GCC-specific thing.  Also, alignment is not guaranteed -- different platforms may have upper limits based on the linker involved.

Comment: As Micheal mentions in his answer, there are two types involved. `struct A` and the type that is aliased by `sampleType`. Those two types are not the same, the `__attribute__` only applies to the later.  AFAIR you could put the `__attribute__` before the `struct` to apply it there. In any case I find it always clearer to separate the two declarations. I'd put a simple `typedef struct A sampleType` first.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to be clear about - only variables using the `sampleType` typedef will have the specified alignment enforced.

Variables declared using `struct A` will not.

And this syntax is a GCC extension - other compilers may or may not support it (MSVC will not, I don't know if LLVM does or not).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `__attribute__` is highly compiler dependent. With gcc, this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct st
{
  int a;
  char b;
} st __attribute__ ((aligned (128)));

static char a;
static st b;
static char c;
static struct st d;

char e;
st f;
char g;
struct st h;

int main()
{
    char i;
    st j;
    char k;
    struct st l;

    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &e, &f, &g, &h);
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &i, &j, &k, &l);
}
```

gives me

```
0x804a100 0x804a180 0x804a188 0x804a18c
0x804a208 0x804a280 0x804a288 0x804a200
0xbfc8d87f 0xbfc8d800 0xbfc8d7ff 0xbfc8d7f4
```

What does that tell?

If really using the `typedef`ed type (`st`), the alignment happens. If I use `struct st`, it doesn't.

If it happens, it happens on `static` variables, on `external`ly linked ones and as well on `automatic` ones (on the stack).

What confuses me is that `h` gets an address before the others...